# Php script to Collect An Array of Nameservers From a Trimmed Zone File (txt file)

Tags: php, arrays, dns

I have got two text files which am working with. The first text file is called get-domain.txt and it contains a list of domains in the following format:

```
000,
1,
10,
101domain,
11,
```

The second file is a trimmed zone file called final-file.txt and it contains domains and their nameservers in the following format:

```
000 NS ns2.mailart.com. 
 NS ns3.mailart.com. 


1 NS NS1.MAILART.COM. 
 NS NS2.MAILART.COM. 


10 NS pns22.cloudns.net.
 NS ns24.cloudns.net. 


101domain NS ns1.101domain.com. 
 NS ns2.101domain.com. 


11 NS f1g1ns1.dnspod.net.
 NS f1g1ns2.dnspod.net.
```

I have written a script to loop through both files and when a domain in the first file matches the one in the second file, I should collect the nameservers for that domain and write them to another file called file-to-compare.txt in the following format:

```
000.mw, ns2.mailart.com.,
000.mw, ns3.mailart.com.,
```

However, the problem I am facing is that the php script I have written is only able to collect the first nameserver. Its not able to get the rest of the nameservers for a domain if they are more than one. Below is the sample output from my script:

```
000.mw, ns2.mailart.com., 
000.mw, ns2.mailart.com.,
```

Below is my code:

```
//open a file to read domains from
$domains = fopen("get-domain-final.txt", "r") or die("Cant open the get-      domain-final file"); //open the file containing all domains
while (!feof($domains))

{
    $dom_arr = array(); $d = 0; //define n declare domain array n its index
    $m=0; //checks if an array contains a value
    $b=0; 
    $array = explode(",", fgets($domains)); //make an array using comma inorder to get the domain
    $domain=$array[0];

    //***************** opening final trimed zone file**********************//
    $exp = "final-file.txt"; 
    $fp = fopen("$exp",'r') or die("Cant open the final trimed zone file"); 

    //***************** opening file to write our results to**********************//
    $regfile = "file-to-compare.txt";  //assign the file to a variable
    $fh = fopen($regfile,'a') or die("Cant open the reg file"); 

    while(!feof($fp)){
         $blank=fgets($fp); //get the line from the file  //it wrkd as well--> $blank=trim(fgets($fp));if(empty($blank))
         $fields = explode(" ",$blank);  //explode the line by space
         //echo $fields[2]."<br/>"; // display de exploded values of array i.e verizon.mw 
         //check for the NS of the same domain as above
         if( ("$domain") == strtolower((trim($fields[0]))) ){ //get NSs of the domain
            //if ("$domain" == "$fields[0]")$b=1;} //ctrl the lines of that domain to read its NS
            //if ($b>=1){break;}
            //echo $fields[2]."<br/>"; //for testing
            $dom_arr[$d++] = $fields[2]; //assign ns to array index
            $m=1;//helps to control of which next lines of that domain to read and get the NSs
            //continue;
        }


        if( ($m==1) && preg_match("/^$/",trim($blank)) ){
            //for($i=0;$i<$d;$i++){
            //  echo $dom_arr[$i]."<br/><br/>";
            break;//} //controls where to stop reading the NS of the domain
          }

        if( ( $m==1)&& (preg_match("/^$/",trim($fields[0])) ) ){ //get NSs of the domain same as above
            //echo $fields[2]."<br/>"; //for testing
            $dom_arr[$d++] = $fields[2]; //assign ns to array index
            //continue;
            }   

        //*************display the name servers and write them to a file**************//
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "NSs of domain $domain:<br/>";
        for($i=0;$i<$d;$i++){ //print out the found NSs
            echo $dom_arr[$i]."<br/>";
            $fields = "$domain.mw, $dom_arr[$i], \n";
             fwrite($fh,$fields);  //add the domains and expiry the to file
             break; //break each for loop
        }
    }
    fclose($fp); //close the final trimed zone file


}//end of while loop for file containing all domains
fclose($domains); //close the file containing all domains
```

Some One Posted A sort of similar question on this link [Returning array of nameservers for domain php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476786/returning-array-of-nameservers-for-domain-php) but the logic we are using is totally different that's why I have proceeded to ask again.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible issues with this script:

1. `fopen($regfile,'a')` will open a file for writing, placing the internal pointer at the *end* of the file. Try using `fopen($regfile,'r+')`which will place the pointer at the *start of the file.
2. You break the `while` loop when encountering a "blank" in a hostname, which will stop the loop dead. Nothing in the code allows the script to start looping again.

Consider using a `continue` statement instead of `break`, which will stop the loop at the marked point, but allow it to continue looping again from the next item in the list.

Comment: thanks @theruss. I have replaced break in the for loop with continue and am able to get the second nameserver. However, the problem now is that the first nameserver is being collected twice. This is the sample output now:000.mw, ns2.mailart.com., 
000.mw, ns2.mailart.com.,
000.mw, ns3.mailart.com.,
1.mw, NS1.MAILART.COM., 
1.mw, NS1.MAILART.COM., 
1.mw, NS2.MAILART.COM., 
10.mw, pns22.cloudns.net.,
10.mw, pns22.cloudns.net., 
10.mw, ns24.cloudns.net.,

Answer (score 0):

First we get all domains into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). Then we loop over each domain with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and remove the comma at the end of the domain with [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php). So we got a `$domains` array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 000
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 101domain
    [4] => 11
)
```

After that we get the nameserver file as string with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). We then split this string with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) by 2 or more new lines, so we got all nameservers for each domain in one array element.

But the nameservers for each domain are not in a very handy format. So we loop over the array and for one get the domain with [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), where we get the substring from the start of the element till the first occurrence of `NS` which position we get with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), and second we get all nameservers with [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), where we get all names after `NS`. Then we have the `$nameservers` array in a handy format like this:

```
Array (
    domain => Array(nameserver1, nameserver2, ...),
    //...
)
```

Now we just need to get the intersection of the two arrays `$domains` and `$nameservers` by key which we can easily do with [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php).

And at the end the only thing left to do is to loop over the intersection and save the data in the format with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Code

```
<?php

    $domains = array_map(function($v){
        return rtrim($v, ",");
    }, file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
    $nameserversTmp = preg_split("/(?=\R\s*\R)[\R\s]+/", file_get_contents("test2.txt"));
    $nameservers = [];

    foreach($nameserversTmp as $nameserver){
        $domain = substr($nameserver, 0, strpos($nameserver, " NS"));
        preg_match_all("/NS ([\w.]+)/", $nameserver, $m);

        $nameservers[$domain] = $m[1];
    }

    $intersect = array_intersect_key($nameservers, array_flip($domains));

    foreach($intersect as $domain => $nameserverList){
        file_put_contents("final.txt", $domain . ".mw, " . implode(", " . PHP_EOL . $domain . ".mw, ", $nameserverList) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }

?>
```

Comment: your code above is really awesome but its only returning One Nameserver for each domain. Sample Output is:                 000.mw, ns2.mailart.com.
1.mw, NS1.MAILART.COM.                                                                                 I want all nameservers for that domain to be collected.

Comment: @dbanda It should work I have tested it. Can you please show me the output of `print_r($domains);` and `print_r($nameservers);`, just post two pastebin links here.

Comment: sorry i dont know how to use pastebin but the value of print_r($domains) is:  Array ( [0] => 000 [1] => 1 [2] => 10 [3] => 101domain [4] => 11 ) and the value of print_r($nameservers) is : Array ( [000] => Array ( [0] => ns2.mailart.com. ) [] => Array ( [0] => f1g1ns2.dnspod.net. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => NS1.MAILART.COM. ) [10] => Array ( [0] => pns22.cloudns.net. ) [101domain] => Array ( [0] => ns1.101domain.com. ) [11] => Array ( [0] => f1g1ns1.dnspod.net. ) )

Comment: @dbanda There is something which you don't show us. Please share some pastbin links with the file data (Make sure the formatting does not change) and instead of using `print_r` to get the array output use `var_dump` and share that output also as a pastebin link. So 2x file output and 2x array output.

Comment: @dbanda That array looks good with `print_r`, just to make sure show me the output with `var_dump` for `$domains` AND `$nameservers`. Just with pastebin links again.

Comment: @dbanda Okay thanks. So your `$domains` array is good. Now there is something wrong in the `$nameservers` array. Please post a pastebin from your `final-file.txt` file. Make sure the formatting of the file stays the same while coping it into pastebin.

Comment: Here is the link to complete file containing nameservers http://pastebin.com/9mtnswgp

Comment: @dbanda Perfect. So the problem was that you had some empty lines not only with a new line character, but also spaces. Updated my answer, the code should work for you now.